# clicking on link after changing its class is changed not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little block of code on something I am working on where a user clicks on an icon to add someone to their buddy list. Once they accept the confirm some ajax runs and I change several elements of the image, including its class.

The click event for this whole thing runs based on the class of the image, it is either `.add_buddy` or `.rem_buddy`

So after the ajax runs I do this:

```
element.attr('src', '/images/icon_user.gif');

element
    .removeClass('add_buddy')
    .addClass('rem_buddy')
    .attr('id', 'rem_buddy_' + buddy_id);

element.attr('alt', 'this member is on your buddy list');

element.attr('title', 'this member is on your buddy list');
```

element BTW is the object (from previous lines of code)

Now if I click back on the image after all the changes it still invokes the click event for the old class. In other words if I click to add a buddy the code above runs and the add_buddy class is removed and the rem_buddy class is added.

When I click on it after the above scenario it triggers the click event for add_buddy, not rem_buddy

I did some alerts to test, including hasClass('add_buddy') which returns false and then hasClass('rem_buddy') that returns true.

Here's is one of the blocks in its entirety for reference

```
$('.add_buddy').click(function()     {

  var buddy_id = str_replace('add_buddy_', '', $(this).attr('id'));
  var element = $(this);

  if (confirm('Add this person to your buddy list?'))   {

    $.ajax({  
      async: false,
      type: 'POST',  
      url: '/forum_functions/functions/add_buddy.php', 
      data: 'buddy_id=' + buddy_id,
      success: function(data, textStatus){
        element.attr('src', '/images/icon_user.gif');
        element.removeClass('add_buddy').addClass('rem_buddy').attr('id', 'rem_buddy_' + buddy_id);
        element.attr('alt', 'this member is on your buddy list');
        element.attr('title', 'this member is on your buddy list');
        }

      });

    }

});
```

Not exactly sure what I am missing here

Answer (score 1):

The reason for such behaviour is that event is bound to particular element(s), that **had the specified selector at the moment of event binding**. Simplified example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.foo')
    .on('click', function() {
      alert($(this).hasClass('foo'));
    })
    .removeClass('foo');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="foo">Bar</button>
```

To avoid this, you should use event delegation:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document)
    .on('click', '.foo', function() {
      alert($(this).hasClass('foo'));
    })
  $('.foo').first().removeClass('foo');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="foo">Foo1</button>
<button class="foo">Foo2</button>
```

More on event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Yeah after walking away from it for a while it dawned on me what I was doing wrong ... been a LONG week.